# SQLCmd Password parameter with comma

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, command-line-arguments, sqlcmd, osql

We have a SQL server for which the password contains `comma (',')`. Since we use the same in `SQLCmd`, the process fails. Please find the query which we are using below

```
SQLCmd -U%1 -P%2 /S%servername% /dDbName -Q"EXEC sp_test null, 'DbName', '\ProcessLog\', 'STORE'" >> %NB4%\ProcessLog.log
```

The string is passing from a different command file.

> But the password contains comma (','), so that the process is not able
>   to connect to SQL Server

Is there a way to add escape character in the parameters? Tried using double quotes ('"'), but no luck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. Since `comma` was there in the `password`, the part after the `comma` was considering as the third parameter and since the first parameter were not matching with the actual password, the connection were not getting established. Here is the solution for this. Worked perfectly for me.

```
IF "%3" NEQ "" GOTO ThreeParm
IF "%3" == "" GOTO TwoParm
:ThreeParm
SQLCMD -U%1 -P%2,%3 /S%servername% /dTestDB -Q"EXEC sp_test null, 'TestDB', '\Folder\', 'STORE'" >> %NB4%\Folder.log
:TwoParm
SQLCMD -U%1 -P%2 /S%servername% /dTestDB -Q"EXEC sp_test null, 'TestDB', '\Folder\', 'STORE'" >> %NB4%\Folder.log
```